# Cannot install vlc on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, vlc, 17.10

I make a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10. Now I`m trying to install VLC but I receive the following message

```
Get:1 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libmad0 amd64 0.15.1b-8ubuntu1 [71,5 kB]
Err:1 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libmad0 amd64 0.15.1b-8ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:4b8439454ba8df807eff531cf20c0fcb505922c250692a5ff667caacd1780083
   - SHA1:25fa86e4b1eaabc396ae0859430b61427cc16e08 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:ba5128e2adc8b08abb99f6036cb3ed11 [weak]
   - Filesize:71550 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:7fca23869648aa4e55dd62590a55a78550e7f8a8de1840f29d444fc66af7fe2a
   - SHA1:202e5fc46143f6e496ff399b9e8a7ea9500be2b8 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:32c52c261efa8aa58a87a41fa816a553 [weak]
   - Filesize:71550 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 21:28:48 +0000
Fetched 71,5 kB in 0s (324 kB/s)  
E: Failed to fetch http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmad/libmad0_0.15.1b-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:4b8439454ba8df807eff531cf20c0fcb505922c250692a5ff667caacd1780083
    - SHA1:25fa86e4b1eaabc396ae0859430b61427cc16e08 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:ba5128e2adc8b08abb99f6036cb3ed11 [weak]
    - Filesize:71550 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:7fca23869648aa4e55dd62590a55a78550e7f8a8de1840f29d444fc66af7fe2a
    - SHA1:202e5fc46143f6e496ff399b9e8a7ea9500be2b8 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:32c52c261efa8aa58a87a41fa816a553 [weak]
    - Filesize:71550 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 21:28:48 +0000
```

Any ideas or suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I suggest you try to use the main server and check again.

Comment: Did you tried other mirror? I have `vlc` installed on Ubuntu 17.10 MATE.

Comment: Yep, I changed to another mirror and now it's working. Could either one of you send an answer for me mark as accept? Maybe others could have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a while ago when one of the third party mirrors got out of sync with the main server. I just switched to a different mirror, and the issue went away. If you're having problems with the mirrors, try the main server for your region instead.

You can select a new mirror via the "Software and Updates" panel:

[image: Software and Updates panel]